# A question on invariant Borel measurable partitions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Imagine $X=[0,1)$ and $T:X \to X$. Let $\mu$ be any $T$-invariant probability measure on $X$. Let $A_1, \cdots, A_m$ is a T-invariant Borel measurable partition of $X$. Set for $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$:
\begin{align}
&B_i=\{J \in \mathcal{P}: \mu(A_i \cap J)>(1-\epsilon)\mu(J)\} \\
&B_0=X \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^mB_i
\end{align}
Where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of atoms.
Then $B_0, B_1, \cdots, B_m$ is a measurable partition of $X$. By elementary measure theory,
\begin{align}
&\mu(A_i \Delta B_i)< \epsilon \\
&\mu(B_0)<m.\epsilon
\end{align}
I couldn't see the reason of the above relations. could anyone help?